# Selenium wont click the first checkbox on the page

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

I am testing a webpage where I need to select a couple of checkboxes and then click submit.

My problem is that which ever checkbox I ask Selenium to click on first is ignored. No matter what order I put them in, the first one it comes to in the code won't be clicked, but conversely the test won't fail, so I know Selenium has at least located it, and thinks it's clicked on it.

Here's the HTML of the check boxes:

```
<ul class="input">
<li class="expandable">
<span class="expand-link collapsed" title="Click to collapse"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="g1:1" name="g1" value="1">
<label for="g1:1">Some text</label>
<ul class="">

<ul class="input">
<li class="expandable">
<span class="expand-link collapsed" title="Click to collapse"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="g2:1" name="g2" value="1">
<label for="g2:1">Some text</label>
<ul class="">
```

I started with this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("g2:1")).click();
```

Each time the second element was clicked but not the first. I then added a WebDriverWait before it, in case it was something to do with that, like so:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1"))));

driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("g2:1")).click();
```

Which had the same problem. I then also tried wrapping them in an 'if' statement to check for the Element's status first, then click it if it's not selected:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1"))));

    if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).isSelected() ) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).click();
    }

    if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("g2:1")).isSelected() ) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("g2:1")).click();
    }
```

None of these things has helped. If I comment out the first checkbox the problem then simple moves to the second one.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

**HTML Snippet**

```
<li class="expandable"> 
<span class="expand-link collapsed" title="Click to collapse"></span> 
<input type="checkbox" id="g1:1" name="g1" value="1"> 
    <label for="g1:1">Some text</label>
</input>
```

Comment: can you share the `HTML` Snippet, what happens if you comment out the second one, does the first one is selected? .. Are you sure its a `checkbox` and not the `radioButton`

Comment: <li class="expandable">
<span class="expand-link collapsed" title="Click to collapse"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="g1:1" name="g1" value="1">
<label for="g1:1">Some text</label>

Comment: can you edit your question and put complete html for both the checkboxes.

Comment: Its working fine on my machine, using your code, both the text box are selected. [Here](http://puu.sh/mmTxL/7de33c3be6.png)

Comment: Which browser are you using, I've tried on firefox and its working perfectly fine. [Screenshot](http://puu.sh/mmTZ2/40123552bc.png)

Comment: I'm using firefox as well. 43.0.4 to be precise, and 2.48.2 of Selenium

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem though, can you try with lower firefox version may be 41.x.x ..

Comment: Does the program entering to the `if(!driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).isSelected())` and trying to execute `driver.findElement(By.id("g1:1")).click();` ?

Answer (score 0):

After some hunting around I never managed to find out why this was happening, but I did end up with a work around that I'll post for the sake of anyone passing through.

By using Selenium's ability to execute specific bits of JavaScript I was able to check the checkbox that way. Keep in mind that I haven't removed the code above, as it would ALWAYS fail the first checkbox, regardless of what it was. Anyway, this is the code that I added to get past the issue:

```
    WebElement firstcheckbox = driver.findElement(By.id("someID"));            
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("jQuery(document.getElementById('someID')).prop('checked', true)", firstcheckbox);
```